# Send email with an avatar

Tags: email, avatar

Few days ago I got an newsletter from an company to my Gmail address and I don't have this company in my contact list. Normally the avatar image is empty when you get some newsletter or email from someone that you don't have in your contact list but this time the company has set a avatar to their newsletter.

Now to my question. Can I specify an image to be shown as an avatar on the emails I'll send from my website? If yes, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The avatar displayed in Gmail is depending on which Google account that is connected to the senders email address. For example if you send your emails from *info@company.org* and have a Gmail (or Google+ etc.) account for that email and added a profile picture it will be displayed.

- Create a Google+/Gmail account starting here: https://gsuite.google.com/signup/basic/welcome It looks like it is not free: **G Suite Basic** is 60 USD per user ; **G Suite Business**: 120 USD per user; and, **G Suite Enterprise** 300 USD per user
- Change your avatar picture, here's how to do it in Gmail:
  http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/how-do-i/put-picture-gmail.php

Comment: This works in gmail. But does it work in google inbox?

Comment: You should checkout this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-authentication-bimi.html